# Load lucene-core dependency at runtime

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, opensearch, resthighlevelclient

I want to use opensearch-rest-high-level-client and elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client libraries within my application.
Both of these jars use different version of lucene-core as dependencies. Is it possible to use different version of lucene-core at runtime?

I tried to find a version of both the libraries with common version of lucene-core, but couldn't find one.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

On the OpenSearch documentation website, there is a [compatibility Matrix](https://opensearch.org/docs/2.9/install-and-configure/upgrade-opensearch/index/#index-compatibility-reference) between Elasticsearch, OpenSearch and Lucene up to OS 2.5 and ES 8.6. Elasticsearch also publishes all its dependencies [here](https://artifacts.elastic.co/reports/dependencies/dependencies-8.10.0.html) (change the version number in the URL to find out).

I'm completing the table found in OS docs below up to the most recent versions.

| Lucene Version | OpenSearch Version | Elasticsearch Version |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9.x | 2.14 (not released yet) | 8.14 (not released yet) |
| 9.10.0 | 2.13 | 8.13 |
| 9.9.2 | 2.12 |  |
| 9.9.1 |  | 8.12 |
| 9.8.0 | 2.11 | 8.11 |
| 9.7.0 | 2.10 | 8.10 |
| 9.7.0 | 2.9.x | 8.9 |
| 9.6.0 | 2.8.x | 8.8 |
| 9.5.0 | 2.6.x / 2.7.x | 8.7 |
| 9.4.2 | 2.5.0 / 2.4.1 | 8.6 |
| 9.4.1 | 2.4.0 | - |
| 9.4.0 | - | 8.5 |
| 9.3.0 | 2.3.0 / 2.2.x | 8.4 |
| 9.2.0 | 2.1.0 | 8.3 |
| 9.1.0 | 2.0.x | 8.2 |
| 9.0.0 | - | 8.1 / 8.0 |
| 8.11.1 | - | 7.17 |
| 8.10.1 | 1.3.x / 1.2.x | 7.16 |
| 8.9.0 | 1.1.0 | 7.15 / 7.14 |
| 8.8.2 | 1.0.0 | 7.13 |
| 8.8.0 | - | 7.12 |
| 8.7.0 | - | 7.11 / 7.10 |
| 8.6.2 | - | 7.9 |
| 8.5.1 | - | 7.8 / 7.7 |
| 8.4.0 | - | 7.6 |
| 8.3.0 | - | 7.5 |
| 8.2.0 | - | 7.4 |
| 8.1.0 | - | 7.3 |
| 8.0.0 | - | 7.2 / 7.1 |
| 7.7.3 | - | 6.8 |